# Errors handling for PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false

Tags: pdo

My codes :

```
$st = $conn->prepare('abc');
echo "emulate is : " . $st->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES) . "<br />";

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM traceuser WHERE username=? ORDER BY gg DESC";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $q->execute(array("zac1987"));
$number_of_rows = $q->fetchColumn();
if($result){ 
    echo "sql query successful";
}else{ 
    echo "sql query fail. ";
    print_r ($q->errorInfo()) ;
}
```

**The output if** `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true` :
emulate is : 1
sql query fail. Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'gg' in 'order clause' ) 

**The output if** `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` :
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in /home/aekcom/public_html/test-countResult-fakePS.php on line 33

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/aekcom/public_html/test-countResult-fakePS.php on line 41

**Question :**
Why getAttribute() is not working if `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` ? How do I check the value of emulate? Or how to make it show "emulate is : 0" ?
How to make `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` show more detail of error message like "*Unknown column 'gg'*" instead of "*function execute() on a non-object*"?

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
$conn->prepare('abc');
```

You have a (very bad) syntax error in the SQL "abc". With emulation, there is no error checking on the prepare, and you fail on execute. Without emulation, you fail on prepare and $st is null or false or whatever.